# WPF data binding help needed from a Guru

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, refactoring

I have a C# class that holds both a single ObservableCollection and an array which holds objects that are ObservableCollections.  The values in the array of objects are calculated from the values in the first base collection.  BindableBase just implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

I have simplified my implementation as much as possible below.

RawDS holds an ObservableCollection of RawData it also holds an array of 10 CalcDS objects which are ObservableCollections of CalcData.

All of this works great.  I have worker threads that accumulate the incoming data calculating the results and filling the array with calculated data.  My problem is data binding all of this to a single chart and grid within WPF.  I have researched, read and tried everything I can find but cannot seem to get the data binding to work with the properties in the RawData and CalcData objects.  I believe that the problem stems from the fact that I am binding to an object that is NOT an ObservableCollection but one that has ObservableCollections within it.  So my question is what two fold.

1. Is there some way to do this kind of data binding?  I have been setting the DataContext of the DataChart and DataGrid to the base object RawDS and attempting to combine everything with DataBindings Source and Path Properties. No joy!
2. If not,  what would be a good way to refactor the data classes below info something that works without having a huge explosion of properties to maintain.  The CalcData class now has 14 properties (times 10),  everything I can think of ends up being one big monolithic class.  Which would be a maintenance nightmare.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class CalcData : BindableBase
{
    private Single _plotValue1;

    public Single PlotValue1
    {
        get { return _plotValue1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _plotValue1, value); }
    }
}

public class CalcDS : ObservableCollection<CalcData>
{
    public CalcDS()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            var cd = new CalcData
            {
                PlotValue1 = random.Next(10, 50)
            };
            Add(cd);
        }
    }
}

public class RawData : BindableBase
{
    private DateTime _xDateTime;
    private Single _plotValue;

    public DateTime XDateTime
    {
        get { return _xDateTime; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _xDateTime, value); }
    }

    public Single PlotValue
    {
        get { return _plotValue; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _plotValue, value); }
    }
}

public class RawDS : BindableBase
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<RawData> _rawMDP = new ObservableCollection<RawData>();
    private readonly CalcDS [] _calcDsDataAry = new CalcDS [10];

    // Initialize things and get the worker thread going.
    public RawDS()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var times = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            var time = new TimeSpan(0, random.Next(0, 5), 0);
            times = times.Add(time);
            var rd = new RawData
            {
                XDateTime = times,
                PlotValue = random.Next(10, 50)
            };
            _rawMDP.Add(rd);
        }

        // Create 10 CalcDS objests numbered 0 to 9
        for (var cnt = 0; cnt < 10; cnt++)
            _calcDsDataAry[cnt] = new CalcDS();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RawData> RawMDP
    { get { return _rawMDP; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData01
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[0]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData02
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[1]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData03
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[2]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData04
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[3]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData05
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[4]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData06
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[5]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData07
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[6]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData08
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[7]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData09
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[8]; } }

    public CalcDS CalcDsData10
    { get { return _calcDsDataAry[9]; } }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the xaml where you are trying to bind

Comment: Thanks for responding. It would be difficult provide the XAML for everything I have tried. So I have created a stripped down VS2010 solution using text and list boxes so you can have a look yourself. How do I attach a zip file here???

Comment: Is _calcDsDataAry always [10]?  If so I would just have a _calcDsData01 _calcDsData02 ... _calcDsData10.  Or use a List rather than and array.

Comment: Well I cannot seem to find any way to attach a zip file project to help with this issue.  .  Is this not possible?  I think it would help a lot to demonstrate what’s going on.  Blam – that is what I outlined in my original post.  It’s doable but would be a maintenance nightmare.  Kelly & Steve Py the array may be part of the issue but I have not even had the non-array _rawMDP ObservableCollection working right.

Comment: Name the [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) you get and post XAML (in the question, forget about files), also please change the title to actually describe your problem, the current one is a catastrophe.

Comment: There are hundreds of errors and they seem to change based on what I have tried. I really thought going into this that someone more skilled than myself would look at what I was trying and say “no that’s not how it’s done, this is the way this type of problem is solved. In any case here is a stripped down VS2010 project that can be used to investigate further. If anyone is so inclined. <http://rapidgator.net/file/60829568/DataBindingTest.rar.html> As far as the title it says exactly what I need. If you do not like it make a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what may work will be wrapping your array in a custom container that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` then subscribe to each item's `PropertyChanged` event (when added to the collection, and unsubscribed when removed/disposed) and raise the `CollectionChanged` event.

I may have time to have a look at it if no one else takes a good stab at a solution.

Comment: I think that the test project is helping. I now do not get any data binding errors but I also do not the desired results. Please see: <http://rapidgator.net/file/60868625/DataBindingTest_2.rar.html> I believe my problem is not knowing how to set the datacontext to an ObservableCollection property within my base object. I have reworked the project so that the test data being created are 4 digit numbers. The first number is 1234 and shows up in the XAML listbox as 4 separate single digit numbers on 4 separate lines. As always thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I should also point out that because the base ObservableCollection and the array of ObservableCollections both show the same problem I believe that if I can fix one the will follow.  Once I have a solution I am sure I will be able to refactor it back into my working MVVM solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an array does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so the UI has no idea the data is changing. Steve Py has a good idea on wrapping it.

If you can change it from an array to an ObservableCollection would make things easier.